# How to create Document objects with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, xmlhttprequest, document, specifications

Basically that's the question, how is one supposed to construct a [Document](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-document) object from a string of HTML dynamically in javascript?

Comment: It's a real Document object. Not sure what you mean by "mere xml/html structure"...

Comment: I mean text, sequence of tags.

Comment: If you look at the [specification of the `send()` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#the-send-method), you'll notice that strings are covered by the "DOMString" case. Therefore, the "Document" case cannot mean a string, it's an object that implements the `Document` interface specified in the DOM standard.

Comment: Yes, I read it, just wanted to clarify, maybe you know any examples of XMLHttpRequest used to send Document object? Side-question still stays though - maybe it's not that wide-spread usage, but how do you construct Document object?

Comment: Now that we cleared that up, I recommend that you edit your question so that the side-question becomes the main question - "How to create Document objects with JavaScript".

Comment: If you don't get a good answer in the next 45 hours, remind me to set a bounty on this...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two methods defined in specifications, [`createDocument`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#Level-2-Core-DOM-createDocument) from DOM Core Level 2 and [`createHTMLDocument`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#dom-domhtmlimplementation-createhtmldocument) from HTML5.  The former creates an XML document (including XHTML), the latter creates a HTML document.  Both reside, as functions, on the `DOMImplementation` interface.

```
var impl    = document.implementation,
    xmlDoc  = impl.createDocument(namespaceURI, qualifiedNameStr, documentType),
    htmlDoc = impl.createHTMLDocument(title);
```

In reality, these methods are rather young and only implemented in recent browser releases.  According to http://quirksmode.org and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument), the following browsers support `createHTMLDocument`:

- Chrome 4
- Opera 10
- Firefox 4
- Internet Explorer 9
- Safari 4

Interestingly enough, you can (kind of) create a HTML document in older versions of Internet Explorer, using `ActiveXObject`:

```
var htmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("htmlfile");
```

The resulting object will be a new document, which can be manipulated just like any other document.

Comment: I note you don't include working code. The only methods I've seen (e.g. on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser)) rely on either built–in browser support for `DOMParser.prototype.parseFromString` or on setting the `innerHTML` property of the new document's HTML element. However, [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and shown in testing) the innerHTML property of HTML elements (and a number of others) is **read only** and can't be set in IE up to and including IE 9.

Comment: @RobG: there's `document.open()`, `document.write()` and `document.close()`. They all work in any browser including IE6 and lower. The only downside is that all the methods for IE6-8 parse and execute JavaScript, which is probably not desirable (it wasn't in [my case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474710/can-i-load-an-entire-html-document-into-a-document-fragment-in-internet-explorer)).

Comment: All good information, but handy to see code. An approach using `document.open` etc. seems to work back to IE 6 and is a useful alternative, however it doesn't work in older Firefox and others whereas the `stringToXMLDoc` function I posted does, as does the `stringToHTMLDoc` function.

Comment: @RobG: Sure, it's always handy to see code, but the question wasn't *"How to create document objects with JavaScript and populate them with HTML?"*, so code like that may be considered unnecessary bloat for an answer, especially considering the OP might have intended to construct the entire document using DOM creation methods. Otherwise, I would genuinely consider adding the code to my answer.  I'd also like to confidently guess that the number of worldwide users with a browser that doesn't support `document.open` is minuscule (Firefox supported it in 1.5), probably not enough to worry about.

Answer (score 28):

Assuming you are trying to create a fully parsed Document object from a string of markup and a content-type you also happen to know (maybe because you got the html from an xmlhttprequest, and thus got the content-type in its `Content-Type` http header; probably usually `text/html`) – it should be this easy:

```
var doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(markup, mime_type);
```

in an ideal future world where browser `DOMParser` implementations are as strong and competent as their document rendering is – maybe that's a good pipe dream requirement for future `HTML6` standards efforts. It turns out no current browsers do, though.

You probably have the easier (but still messy) problem of having a string of html you want to get a fully parsed `Document` object for. Here is another take on how to do that, which also ought to work in all browsers – first you make a HTML `Document` object:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('');
```

and then [populate it with your html fragment](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#dynamic-markup-insertion):

```
doc.open();
doc.write(html);
doc.close();
```

Now you should have a fully parsed DOM in doc, which you can run `alert(doc.title)` on, slice with css selectors like `doc.querySelectorAll('p')` or ditto XPath using `doc.evaluate`.

This actually works in modern WebKit browsers like Chrome and Safari (I just tested in Chrome 22 and Safari 6 respectively) – here is an example that takes the current page's source code, recreates it in a new document variable `src`, reads out its title, overwrites it with a html quoted version of the same source code and shows the result in an iframe: http://codepen.io/johan/full/KLIeE

Sadly, I don't think any other contemporary browsers have quite as solid implementations yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, the last method fails in Opera (12.12): `doc.open()`   `write` / `close` affects the current document instead of the `doc` document. IE6+, Firefox 4+, Chrome 1+ and Safari 3.2+ correctly supports this method. I've already submitted a bug report to Opera.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't check, and it seems an embarrassing enough bug to fix (or at least we can hope for the best) somewhat swiftly. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Per the spec ([doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Level-2-Core-DOM-createDocument)), one may use the `createHTMLDocument` method of `DOMImplementation`, accessible via `document.implementation` as follows:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('My title');  
var body = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'body'); 
doc.documentElement.appendChild(body);
// and so on
```

- jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Fh7R/
- MDN document for `DOMImplementation`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.implementation
- MDN document for `DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument`: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument

Comment: Note that the MDN code fails in IE 9 and lower since it doesn't support setting the HTML element's innerHTML property (it's read only). If you insert a complete HTML document (including a head element) into a BODY element, you are depending on browser error correction of what becomes invalid markup at the moment it is assigned.

Answer (score 4):

The following works in most common browsers, but not some. This is how simple it **should** be (but isn't):

```
// Fails if UA doesn't support parseFromString for text/html (e.g. IE)
function htmlToDoc(markup) {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  return parser.parseFromString(markup, "text/html");
}

var htmlString = "<title>foo bar</title><div>a div</div>";
alert(htmlToDoc(htmlString).title);
```

To account for user agent vagaries, the following may be better (please note attribution):

```
/*
 * DOMParser HTML extension
 * 2012-02-02
 *
 * By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com
 * Public domain.
 * NO WARRANTY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.
 *
 * Modified to work with IE 9 by RobG
 * 2012-08-29
 *
 * Notes:
 *
 *  1. Supplied markup should be avalid HTML document with or without HTML tags and
 *     no DOCTYPE (DOCTYPE support can be added, I just didn't do it)
 *
 *  2. Host method used where host supports text/html
 */

/*! @source https://gist.github.com/1129031 */
/*! @source https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser */

/*global document, DOMParser*/

(function(DOMParser) {
    "use strict";

    var DOMParser_proto;
    var real_parseFromString;
    var textHTML;         // Flag for text/html support
    var textXML;          // Flag for text/xml support
    var htmlElInnerHTML;  // Flag for support for setting html element's innerHTML

    // Stop here if DOMParser not defined
    if (!DOMParser) return;

    // Firefox, Opera and IE throw errors on unsupported types
    try {
        // WebKit returns null on unsupported types
        textHTML = !!(new DOMParser).parseFromString('', 'text/html');

    } catch (er) {
      textHTML = false;
    }

    // If text/html supported, don't need to do anything.
    if (textHTML) return;

    // Next try setting innerHTML of a created document
    // IE 9 and lower will throw an error (can't set innerHTML of its HTML element)
    try {
      var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('');
      doc.documentElement.innerHTML = '<title></title><div></div>';
      htmlElInnerHTML = true;

    } catch (er) {
      htmlElInnerHTML = false;
    }

    // If if that failed, try text/xml
    if (!htmlElInnerHTML) {

        try {
            textXML = !!(new DOMParser).parseFromString('', 'text/xml');

        } catch (er) {
            textHTML = false;
        }
    }

    // Mess with DOMParser.prototype (less than optimal...) if one of the above worked
    // Assume can write to the prototype, if not, make this a stand alone function
    if (DOMParser.prototype && (htmlElInnerHTML || textXML)) { 
        DOMParser_proto = DOMParser.prototype;
        real_parseFromString = DOMParser_proto.parseFromString;

        DOMParser_proto.parseFromString = function (markup, type) {

            // Only do this if type is text/html
            if (/^\s*text\/html\s*(?:;|$)/i.test(type)) {
                var doc, doc_el, first_el;

                // Use innerHTML if supported
                if (htmlElInnerHTML) {
                    doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
                    doc_el = doc.documentElement;
                    doc_el.innerHTML = markup;
                    first_el = doc_el.firstElementChild;

                // Otherwise use XML method
                } else if (textXML) {

                    // Make sure markup is wrapped in HTML tags
                    // Should probably allow for a DOCTYPE
                    if (!(/^<html.*html>$/i.test(markup))) {
                        markup = '<html>' + markup + '<\/html>'; 
                    }
                    doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(markup, 'text/xml');
                    doc_el = doc.documentElement;
                    first_el = doc_el.firstElementChild;
                }

                // RG: I don't understand the point of this, I'll leave it here though 
                //     In IE, doc_el is the HTML element and first_el is the HEAD.
                //
                // Is this an entire document or a fragment?
                if (doc_el.childElementCount == 1 && first_el.localName.toLowerCase() == 'html') {
                    doc.replaceChild(first_el, doc_el);
                }

                return doc;

            // If not text/html, send as-is to host method
            } else {
                return real_parseFromString.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        };
    }
}(DOMParser));

// Now some test code
var htmlString = '<html><head><title>foo bar</title></head><body><div>a div</div></body></html>';
var dp = new DOMParser();
var doc = dp.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');

// Treat as an XML document and only use DOM Core methods
alert(doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].childNodes[0].data);
```

Don't be put off by the amount of code, there are a lot of comments, it can be shortened quite a bit but becomes less readable.

Oh, and if the markup is valid XML, life is much simpler:

```
var stringToXMLDoc = (function(global) {

  // W3C DOMParser support
  if (global.DOMParser) {
    return function (text) {
      var parser = new global.DOMParser();
      return parser.parseFromString(text,"application/xml");
    }

  // MS ActiveXObject support
  } else {
    return function (text) {
      var xmlDoc;

      // Can't assume support and can't test, so try..catch
      try {
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async="false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
      } catch (e){}
      return xmlDoc;
    }
  }
}(this));


var doc = stringToXMLDoc('<books><book title="foo"/><book title="bar"/><book title="baz"/></books>');
alert(
  doc.getElementsByTagName('book')[2].getAttribute('title')
);
```

Comment: Like I said in reply to your comment on my answer, IE6-9 can be coerced into parsing a document using a combination of the `open()`, `write()` and `close()` members of `document`, and this can be done in conjunction with `new ActiveXObject("htmlfile")`.  If you're not worried about script execution in IE 6-8, this is a much shorter/easier approach. Your modification to Eli Grey's code could also use these methods and cut the size down significantly.

Answer (score 4):

An updated answer for 2014, as the DOMparser has evolved. This works in all current browsers I can find, and should work too in earlier versions of IE, using ecManaut's document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('') approach above.

Essentially, IE, Opera, Firefox can all parse as "text/html". Safari parses as "text/xml".

Beware of intolerant XML parsing, though. The Safari parse will break down at non-breaking spaces and other HTML characters (French/German accents) designated with ampersands. Rather than handle each character separately, the code below replaces all ampersands with meaningless character string "j!J!". This string can subsequently be re-rendered as an ampersand when displaying the results in a browser (simpler, I have found, than trying to handle ampersands in "false" XML parsing).

```
function parseHTML(sText) {
try {

    console.log("Domparser: " + typeof window.DOMParser);

    if (typeof window.DOMParser !=null) {
        // modern IE, Firefox, Opera  parse text/html
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(sText, "text/html");
        if (doc != null) {
            console.log("parsed as HTML");
            return doc

        }
        else {

            //replace ampersands with harmless character string to avoid XML parsing issues
            sText = sText.replace(/&/gi, "j!J!");
            //safari parses as text/xml
            var doc = parser.parseFromString(sText, "text/xml");
            console.log("parsed as XML");
            return doc;
        }

    } 
    else  {
        // older IE 
        doc= document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('');
        doc.write(sText);           
        doc.close;
        return doc; 
    }
} catch (err) {
    alert("Error parsing html:\n" + err.message);
}
}
```