# Manipulate a proper html doc as a string and convert back to string

Tags: jquery, html, parsing

Previously when I've needed to manipulate the contents of some html in a string I would do something like this

```
$('<div>').html(someHtmlString).find('#name').text("George").end().html()
```

this works great for an html fragment but in this particular case I'm getting the contents of an iframe as a string - so it's a string representing a full html **document** which I need to manipulate in the same way. This trick, or even just wrapping the string in jQuery no longer works.

[Here is a jsbin demonstrating the issue](http://jsbin.com/ecaduc/2/edit)

```
html = """
<html>
<head>
  <style>* { box-sizing: border-box; }</style
</head>
<body style="max-height: 750px">
  <style> body { background-color: 'lavender'; }</style>
  <div>
    <p>Hi</p>
    <p id="name">Your Name</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
"""

$html = $(html)
$html.find('#name').text("George")

console.log $html.html()
```

How do I parse and manipulate a full html document?

Note that the head might contain style elements and the body might have attributes that I do not want to lose. I'm also seeing odd serialization when the document contains an svg.

I'm not hellbent on jQuery if there's another library that would make more sense to bring in here

Comment: `style` tag within `body` tag? That's invalid markup.

Comment: The `style` tag not invalid if it's `scoped` (and the doc is HTML5, of course).  Back to the question... I can think of a few rather unsavory ways to deal with this, but generally, if I'm ever tempted to try something like those ways in the first place, I have to wonder if I'm just avoiding a bigger problem with ugly patchwork.

Comment: @undefined I don't think that is correct. According to MDN style is `Metadata content, If the scoped attribute is present: flow content` so in at least one case it's definitely allowed, and in another it's the same category as link or script

Comment: @JayC - that's an interesting point. I still think the question is valid and would like to hear a resilient way of achieving this, but in my case I think I could probably achieve my goal by dropping down a level from my api and manipulating the iframe document directly

Answer (score 2):

The most sane approach may be just to create a document with your string ( see [How to create Document objects with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227612/how-to-create-document-objects-with-javascript)), manipulate it (whether jQuery can manipulate it or not, I'm not sure, but I think so) and then grab whatever contents you need from it.  You *would* have to assume that the html is proper, or at least parses into (as identical as possible) DOM trees.  I notice in your example, the head tag has a style tag with an invalid end tag, so I don't know how that'd work in all browsers under consideration.

(Sorry, no working example yet. I'm kinda busy this morning, but I just wanted to put that thought out there).