# Parse dynamically loaded document on background using createHTMLDocument

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8231372/607407), I'm trying to load document via ajax and find contents of specific document node(s) so that I can display them without re-navigating browser.

However, my document always seems to be an empty document.

#### Ajax callback:

```
function processRatingToken(data) {  //Data is just standart HTML document string
  var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
  doc.open();
  //Replace scripts
  data = data.replace(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi, "");
  //Write HTML to the new document
  doc.write(data);
  doc.close();

  console.log(doc.body);  //Empty
}
```

So what's wrong?

<sub>**Note:** I'm using this strategy, because I'm building a [Greasemonkey Userscript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/). If you are developing an Ajax application, this strategy is NOT recomended. Use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) instead.</sub>

Comment: It seems you cannot use `document.write` method due to cross-original policy in your greasemonkey userscript.

Comment: No errors were thrown. And how come `.getElementById` works properly...?

Comment: The CORS limitiation seems to be for `open/write` methods only. But not sure why. [see mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open)

Comment: So the question is how to avoid changing document origin by document write...

Comment: You found ya a way out with `innerHTML`. And I would say `innerHTML` is more prefered, than `document.write`! Or are there some other circumstances, that you need to use `write`?

Comment: Yep, there are circumstances when I may want the scripts to be executed (including more document writes). Maybe there could be some `iframe` workaround. For this specific case `.innerHTML` is just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround with `.innerHTML` property:

```
doc.childNodes[1].innerHTML = data;
```

Where `.childNodes[1]` is the `<html>` element.

Comment: To reference a `<html>` you can use `doc.documentElement` instead of this 'magic' )