# Outlook Desktop add-in Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

how to parse `img src="~WRS%7b700542CA-4646-8E49-B829-78952E169109%7d.fld/image001.jpg"`？I need help，Please tell me。i am a novice，I want to know how to parse the `img src` attribute in the mail body obtained from `Office.context.mailbox.item.getAttachmentContentAsync` in add-in on outlook desktop side

I don't how to parse it。

Answer (score 0):

You can find the required HTML tag in the string and then use the [substring()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) JavaScript function.

Also if you convert the string to the HTMLDocument you can extract the value using the following code:

```
var imgsrc = document.getElementById('img_tag_id').src;
console.log(imgsrc);
```

See [How to convert an HTML string into an HTML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756943/how-to-convert-an-html-string-into-an-html-document) for more information.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for answering me, I have tried to get the src, but the obtained src path does not seem to be the real path

Comment: The src I get when I check the email scene can be parsed, for example: src="cid:image001.png@01D9B357.F2A449C0", but the src I get when replying to the email seems to be encrypted by outlook, for example: src= "~WRS%7bE6D62052-25EC-434B-9BB8-B93D6FAA7D94%7d.fld/image001.jpg", I want to know how to get the real attachment id and the real src path like checking email

Comment: You are dealing with an embedded image. Such images can be found as attached files to your email. Try to check out the the attachments list with the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` MAPI property value specified after the `cid:` prefix.

Comment: I'm not very clear what you mean, can you give me some examples for reference

Comment: But the img src in the body I get in reply to the body of the email does not allow me to successfully call Office.context.mailbox.item.getAttachmentContentAsync, for example WRS%7bE6D62052-25EC-434B-9BB8-B93D6FAA7D94%7d.fld/image001.jpg

Comment: Your original post is about parsing the `src` attribute. If you have any other questions I'd suggest posting new questions in new threads, so users could recognize questions and answers easily.