# Run document.getElementById on unappended HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

I have got created a rather complex HTMLElement and would like to know id there is a way to run a getElementById on it before the element gets appended to the DOM.

What I have tried is to call the function like this:`document.getElementById.call(newElement, "id");`

and like this: `Document.prototype.getElementById.call(newElement, "id");`

in both cases the I just get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Is there a posibility to do that or is it just not possible?

**Note:** I am trying to solve a JS problem here, thats why I do not want jQuery solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
var yourElement = newElement.querySelector('#someId');
```

Complete example :

```
var newElement = document.createElement('div');
newElement.innerHTML="<div id=a>AA</div><span id=b>BB</span>";
console.log(newElement.querySelector('#b').innerHTML) // logs BB
```

Note : [IE7 isn't supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.querySelector)

Comment: +1 the only other option seems to be [creating another document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227612/how-to-create-document-objects-with-javascript) and appending the element into it - that will give you a `getElementById` method.