# Create a New HTML Document Including Doctype

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml, outerhtml

If I do:

```
let html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
    </body>
</html>`;

let newHTMLDocument = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument().documentElement;

newHTMLDocument.innerHTML = html;

console.log( newHTMLDocument );
```

The output is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why isn't the doctype tag included? What do I need to do so that when I output newHTMLDocument, it includes the doctype tag?

Answer (score 4):

**[`.documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement)** returns the `<html>` element (the element at the root of the document - - `<!doctype>` is not an element, it's a declaration node), so you are excluding the `doctype` yourself.

If you get rid of `.documentElement`, the `doctype` remains.

```js
let html = `<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
    </body>
</html>`;

let newHTMLDocument = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();
newHTMLDocument.innerHTML = html;

// You can access the doctype as an object:
console.log("The <!doctype> is a node type of: " +newHTMLDocument.doctype.nodeType,
            "\nWhile the documentElement is a node type of: " + newHTMLDocument.documentElement.nodeType);
console.log(newHTMLDocument.doctype);

alert(newHTMLDocument.innerHTML);
```

Comment: I tried your code but if I do a console.log(newHTMLDocument); it doesn't contain my elements, title tag and p tag. I need all of my elements in an object because I'm going to be using some JS DOM functions on the object.

Comment: @GTSJoe newHTMLDocumemt is an object, you don’t log it directly. My code logs it’s .innerHTML. You can get any of its contents with newHTMLDocument.querySelector(), for example.

Comment: For reference, I ended up using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227612/how-to-create-document-objects-with-javascript/13222848#13222848 which uses createHTMLDocument doc.open();
doc.write(html);
doc.close(); to create an HTML object

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`createDocumentType()`](https://mdn.io/createDocumentType) with [`createHTMLDocument()`](https://mdn.io/createHTMLDocument) or [`createDocument()`](https://mdn.io/createDocument):

```js
const doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('title');
console.log('before', new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc));

const docType = document.implementation.createDocumentType('qualifiedNameStr', 'publicId', 'systemId');
doc.doctype.replaceWith(docType);
console.log('after', new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc));
```