# How do I overwrite an entire document with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This is not a duplicate question for these reasons:

- I am asking about how to replace the entire HTML document with JavaScript without jQuery or any other fancy extensions to JavaScript. Some of the other questions that are similar to this question deal with specific things like AJAX or jQuery.
- I am NOT asking about why `document.write()` only appends to the page. Perhaps the pure JavaScript solution I am looking for may incorporate that function, but it cannot only be that since it is inadequate by itself.

What I am looking to do is overwrite a webpage as it is displayed in the browser with only HTML. The function `document.write()` only appends whatever argument is passed to it to the document's body. The property `document.documentElement.outerHTML` can be read from, but unlike when it is used on a page's child elements, cannot be written to, and even if it could, it would leave the DOCTYPE untouched.

I am working on a bookmarklet, so this JavaScript would not run in the page, meaning there is no problem with the script being overwritten while it is running. It could also be run in the browser's developer tools.

As an example, suppose I have `about:blank` opened in my browser. The contents of the DOM would look like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to overwrite it with whatever string I want. So, for instance, I could make it look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is an example.</p>
    </body>
 </html>
```

How can I achieve that sort of overwrite of a document?

Comment: From what I can see the only way to do it is to modify each section. I would suggest perhaps thinking of refactoring your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
function one() {
  document.write('<html><body><pre>the first html</pre></body></html>');
  document.close();    // this makes the difference
}
function two() {
  document.write('<html><body><pre>the second html</pre></body></html>');
  document.close();
}
```

Refer to [linstantnoodles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23787551/11912992) in question `document.write() overwriting the document?`, the `document.open` is implicitly called before the `document.write` is called, but the `document.close` doesn't, and
`document.write()` when document is closed = rewrite the document;
`document.write()` when document is open = append to the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.implementation.createDocumentType` to rewrite the doctype and `document.getElementsByTagName` to get the DOM elements, then rewrite with `innerHTML` and `setAttribute`.

```js
var newDoctype = document.implementation.createDocumentType('html','-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN','http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtdd');
    document.doctype.parentNode.replaceChild(newDoctype,document.doctype);
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');


var doc = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = '<title>Example</title>';
    doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = '<p>This is an example.</p>';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

Updated to include comments by Xweque and xmlns attribute.

Comment: Nope. That cannot be used to rewrite the entire document. For one thing, it leaves the DOCTYPE untouched.

Comment: Why do you need to rewrite the doctype?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147750/how-can-i-change-the-doctype

Comment: The DOCTYPE is a read-only property. It can be changed [as you can see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147750/how-can-i-change-the-doctype) however it will not actually update the DOCTYPE of the document. DOCTYPE is a [read-only property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/doctype)

Comment: @mhatch Because it is what I desire to be able to do.

Comment: It can be "changed" in that when you check what doctype the document has it will be what you've made it but it will not change what the browser renders. This may wary but running tests in Chrome 56 and Firefox 50 confirms this.

Comment: @mhatch It is so I can display the current page's document tree and then use my own DOCTYPE (XHTML) to display it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.write('Some Text')
```

`document.write` rewrites the page's code.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already mentioned *document.write()* so for the record here’s another couple of methods:

First, set up your new page as desired in a string...

```
var NewPage='<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body>Hello</body></html>';
```

Now load it via the **scrdoc** attribute...

```
Frame_ID.srcdoc=NewPage;
```

Or the **src** attribute like this...

```
Frame_ID.src='data:text/html;charset=utf-8,'+encodeURIComponent(NewPage);
```